# Missing messages when order is important

Tags: architecture, messaging, nservicebus

I am dealing with a situation where I receive messages from a device in the field. These messages have been stamped with a sequence number and I am required to process these messages in the original order. It is rare that messages would go missing but not impossible so I need a to mechanism to deal with it.

My implementation is built on NServiceBus and I am making use of the "HandleCurrentMessageLater" feature to pop the message onto the back of the queue in the event that the message has been received out of order.

This works well provided that I do eventually receive the next message in the sequence so I can process the backlog.

What options do I have to deal with missing messages in this case? My first reaction is to implement some kind of ageing algorithm which would increase the sequence number after a set number of failed attempts or something similar, however the complexity of having to do this is a little over whelming.

Has any one faced a similar problem and willing to share how they solved it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want all subsequent messages to eventually fail if one message goes missing?

Comment: I would need to accept that the message has been lost at some point and process the data which I have. We are dealing with tracking information so we need to limit data loss under all circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like this is something you will need input from the business on. Is there a time limit after which that message can be assumed to be irrevocably lost? And if so, what are the business actions that should be taken in such a case? And what should happen if that message is finally received but after the timeout?

Those sorts of cases you could implement with a Saga. If a message arrives and is out of sequence, then you would still call HandleCurrentMessageLater, but you would also request a timeout so that if those conditions are still true after the business-approved timeout, then the compensating actions can run and the rest of the backed-up messages can be processed.

Or, an alternative solution may be possible. You said that you are required to process the messages in the original order. You don't go into any detail on the real-life implications of this, but that sounds like a high-level business requirement, but not a technical requirement. In other words, that's how the business wants to see it, but it doesn't have to be the way it really happens. Maybe you can process in-order messages normally and also increment a value that indicates which sequence number the collected data is valid for. If messages arrive out of order, they can still be soft-processed, but the sequence number is not incremented.

So basically you receive messages 1-5 and process them normally. Then you receive 7-10 (6 has been skipped) and you process them, but the ValidSequenceNumber is still 5. Then when #6 arrives, you process it, take any compensating actions to catch up, and the ValidSequenceNumber is now 10. A Saga would be a good candidate to implement this kind of logic as well.

Comment: Thanks David. I decided that i'm going to use a more manual approach to report on this condition which will allow me to fix it manually for the time being. I want to understand how often, and more importantly why it happened, before I put an automated mechanism in place.

Answer (score 1):

David Boike has the right answer when using NSB sagas. I'd like to add another option. If the messages are produced in a short amount of time the device could use NSBs capabilities to batch multiple logical messages into one transport message. Just use the `Send` or `Publish` overload of `IBus` which takes multiple message params. These batches are guaranteed to be processed in order.

Comment: Thanks, We are batching messages as is however it is not possible to batch all messages in a specific sequence. The information is collected over a long period of time, and we need to process the information as it becomes available. This is a business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need all messages reliably delivered and your transmission channel is not reliable, then you would need an acknowledge-and-retransmit mechanism. This could look as follows.

Normal flow:

1. After sending a message, the client temporarily stores the message in order to be able to retransmit if needed.
2. Upon sucessful in-seqence transmission, the server sends an acknowledgement message to the client, including the sequence number.
3. With receivng the ACK, the client removes the respective message from its temporarily message store.

Lost message:

1. With detection of an out-of-sequence condition, the server sends a re-transmit message to the client, including the sequence number of the last successfully recieved message.
2. The client re-sends all messages succeeding the last received messages.

This obviously requires a two-way communication, with a transmission channel from server to client.

This problem has been solved in-depth for the TCP protocol which guarantees in-sequence transmission. You may want to have a look at TCP retransmission internals.

Comment: Thanks Bernd, we have a mechanism like this in place. But under extreme conditions we may still lose a message. For instance if there is an error which occurs on the device and the message is simply not sent. A number of things could cause this, such as total power loss to the device etc.